# How to transition to Instagram Graph API for /users/self/media

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I have an app that uses the Instagram API. Basically, users log in with Instagram and it accesses the /users/self/media/recent endpoint to get posts from their personal account. I don't see a way to do this in the new Instagram Graph API, which only seems to work for business accounts. Also it seems to require Facebook login and users to have connected their Instagram to a Facebook page. Is there a way in the Graph API to have users login to their Instagram personal account and access their posts or is this going to disappear in 2020?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot login and get any Instagram account info with Graph API currently, so continue using the old API, it will not deprecate until 2020, In 2019, they have plans to allow all accounts other than business account with Graph API, then u can migrate to it.

Comment: Cool, hopefully I'll be able to migrate in 2019

Comment: 2019 is nearly over and I'm still not sure whether the new Graph API allows to read normal user data, like the old API. Also will the old API still be usable after 2019 ends?

Comment: @HaseebBurki There has been no update from the Instagram team. Only time will tell :(